# Кроссдоменный запрос для django

Tags: ajax, django, cross-domain

Помогите пожалуйста разрешить кроссдоменныйй запрос на локальной машине.

У меня на локальной машине поднят апач. на хосте

```
http://localhost/rurun/
```

есть яваскриптовый фронтэнд.

Так же локально запущен django 1.11. Запущен командой:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Это значит, что используется встроенный сервер.

На django установлен следующий [пакет](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers)

Так же в конфиге прописано следующее:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'statistic',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

После клика на кнопке, из фронэнда отправляется ajax-запрос к django. Но браузер в консоль выводит сообщение об ошибке:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8000/days. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
>   The response had HTTP status code 400.

Вот более подробная информация из вкладки network:

```
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/days
Request Method:GET
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000
Response Headers
view source
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Thu, 29 Jun 2017 17:52:08 GMT
Server:WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.5.2
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Host:127.0.0.1:8000
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/rurun/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
X-Compress:null
```

Ещё пробовал в конфиге прописывать разрешённые хосты в белом листе:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost/rurun'
)
```

Разные комбинации протоколов и портов тоже прбовал

UPD: сейчас заметил, что консоль джанги вываливает такую ошибку:

> DisallowedHost at / Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '127.0.0.1:8000'. You
>   may need to add '127.0.0.1' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Я коненчо попробовал в белом листе прописать этот адрес и перезапустить сервер. Но сообщение об этой ошибке по-прежнему осталось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost']
```

Если не поможет можно попробывать

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0', 'localhost']
```

Comment: @andreymal, сам не пойму...

Comment: Скорее всего у него в request. META передается localhost, по моим наблюдениям django принципиально не хочет принимать ничего, кроме того что прописано в ALLOWED_HOSTS. То есть между localhost и 127.0.0.1 есть разница